# Javascript to change text of a span within div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My html is like this, I can only identify the `div`'s class, there are no `span`' ids. I need to replace one `href` text and one image with some other text within those `span`s.

```
<div class ="myclass">
    <span style="vertical-align:middle;">
      <a href="http://link1"></a>
    </span>

    <span style="vertical-align:middle;">
      <a href="http://link2"></a>
    </span>

    <span style="vertical-align:middle">
      <span class="myspan">
        <a href="http://testlink3">
        <img title="test" class="imglink"></a>
      </span>
    </span>

    <span>
      <a href="http://link4">Text - *This text needs to be replaced*</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

in the above code, I need to replace the `img` within the third `span` with a clickable text (which should take us to url) and the text within fourth `span` to a new text (keeping the url the same).

How can I get identify these specific `span`s when they are missing ids/classes?

Comment: Why don't you just give them IDs?

Comment: there is a closing `</a>` missing, typo or not there?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: @Blazemonger the code was getting generated from an XSLT, I cant give them IDS, it is not in my hand.

Comment: Is it ok for <code>img</code> tags to be inside a <code>span</code>?

Comment: As an alternative, If it's *always* the last `<a>` element, [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) for `$('a').last().text()`

Comment: @tasteslikejava Yes. [`<img>`s](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/img.html#img-context) can be placed inside [phrasing elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/common-models.html#common.elem.phrasing), which includes `<span>`s. (Also: You can use [backticks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) to format [inline code](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/img.html#img-context) in comments.)

Comment: Ok, thank you. I always thought `spans` were for text.

Comment: @svs, where a text, which wil replace *This text needs to be replaced*, should be taken from? Is it constant for all the replaces?

Answer (score 1):

We have 3 different things to do here:

**How to replace the content inside a given element**

This can be done very quickly:

```
$("selector").html("New text, same href");
```

**Replace a given element with another**

This can be done this way:

```
$("selector").replaceWith("<a href='somewhere.html'>I replaced  an Img</a>");
```

**Selecting the DOM elements**

When you don't have an ID, nor a CSS class for your element, but you do know its position within another element plus some info about the element (like tagName), you can select the parent element and specify a relative position.

```
var myElement = $("parentElement").find("tagName:eq(position)");
```

Remember that this kind of selector ( **"tagName:eq(position)"**) is **zero indexed**, so if you want to grab the third element, you need to tell jQuery **tagName:eq(2)**.

So, let's say you parent element (not given in the question) is a **div** with a **parent** CSS class.

First thing you want to do is select this div.

```
var parent = $(".parent");
```

Then you want to find the Img within the third span.

```
var myImg = parent.find("span:eq(2)").find("img");
```

Now you can replace this element with the whatever you want

```
myImg.replaceWith("<a href='somewhere.html'>I replaced  an Img</a>");
```

**Note** that jQuery allows you to pass HTML elements as a plain string.

Finally, you need to change the text inside the fourth span. This can be accomplished this way:

```
parent.find("span:eq(3)").find("a").html("New text, same href");
```

Comment: This one is replacing the text only on the second span and i need them to be replaced on third and forth spans

Comment: Take a closer look. **var myImg = parent.find("span:eq(2)").find("img");** this selects the img in the third span, while **parent.find("span:eq(3)").find("a").html("New text, same href");** does the magic on the fourth one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `document.querySelector` to select an `a` based on the `href`:

```
document.querySelector("a[href='http://link4']").innerHTML = "The text you want to put in"
```

Since you're open to jQuery, this works too:

```
$("a[href='http://link4']").text("The text you want to put in")
```

Comment: href is dynamic, it will varie for each refresh, so I cannot identify it based on url.

Comment: Is it always going to be in the last `span` of the `div`? Also, what's the `class` of your `div`?

Comment: yes, there links are always going to be third and fourth span of the div. Added div class to the code, please see above.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `:nth-child()` selector to select from the `div` you can identify.

More on `:nth-child()`: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Then select the `img` tag from the child `span` you found.

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

var i = spans[2].firstChild.children[1]; // here you find your img
i.parentNode.appendChild(<<your new text element>>);
i.parentNode.removeChild(img);// remove the image

var a = spans[3].firstChild; // here is your href
a.innerHTML = 'your new text';
```